# Why a wrong number of 1 is printed?

Tags: arrays, c, function, matrix, random

My function should randomly insert a user-chosen number of 1 into my matrix. The difficulty lies in the fact that if a cell contains a 1 the cells around it must be set to 0. Why my code print a wrong number of 1? In the code below I had thought to first set the entire matrix to 0, then randomly generate a cell to be set to 1, after having checked it contains 0 and the distance between this cell and other cells containing 1 is >= 1. All this is done until the number m entered by the user becomes 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void initialize(int n, int a[n][n]);
void createMap(int n, int a[n][n], int m);
int check (int i, int j, int v, int w);
void print(int n, int a[n][n]);

int main(){
    
    int n;
    printf("Insert square matrix size: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    int m;
    printf("Insert 1s number: ");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    
    int a[n][n];
    
    initialize(n,a);
    createMap(n,a,m);
    
}

//Filling the matrix with 0
void initialize(int n, int a[n][n]){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            a[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

//Setting in random position 1 value
void createMap(int n, int a[n][n], int m){
    int x1; int x2;
    int b[0][0];
    while (m > 0){
        int i = rand() % n;
        int j = rand() % n;
        if (a[i][j] == 0 && (check(i,j,x1,x2) == 1)){
            a[i][j] = 1;
            m--;
            //I have to fill b array with coordinates and then to pass
            //b array to check function to do the check in the whole b array
        }
    }
    print(n,a);
}

//checking if I can set the value to 1
int check (int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){
    if (sqrt(pow((x1-x2),2) + pow((y1-y2),2)) >= 1){
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

//Printing the matrix
void print(int n, int a[n][n]){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            printf("\t%d",a[i][j]);
        }
        puts("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After generating the coordinates i and j, you should calculate the distance between that cell and the other cells set to 1. You can use the [Manhattan formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) to do that.
If the distance between the newly generated cell and the other cells set to 1 is grater than or equal to 1, you can go ahead and generate the other ones, otherwise you should set it back to zero and generate new coordinates.

Comment: Can you show me a few lines of code? How can i know where all the other cells set to 1 are?

Comment: @ChiaraTumminelli you should save the coords of the other cells in a data structure (array or linked list).

`distance = sqrt(pow((x1 - x2), 2) + pow((y1 - y2), 2));`
x1,y1 are the coords of the first cell and x2,y2 the coords of the other one. If distance >= 1 then the two cells are sufficiently distant from each other

Comment: I tried to write the function, I need to figure out how to insert the coordinates in a new array and do the check on the whole array. can you help me? I edited the post with the modified code.

Answer (score 0):

This is homework right?

A few issues:

1. You have a variable `matrix` that you don't use.
2. You set `a[k][l] = 1;` before you know what the old value was, and therefore can't tell if `m` should be incremented or not.
3. Your bounds checking is messy, it is difficult to see if it is correct, and if you update `m` and all array elements around `a[k][l]` correctly. Nobody wants to look at messy code, unless they get paid. They will just assume that it is wrong. So that part of the code is by definition wrong, and nobody can tell you why.
4. Your bounds checking assumes you have a `4x4` array.

... and a few others.

Point 1 is easy to fix, and it is not important. It just adds to the ugliness of your code.

Point 2 is solved by only updating `a[k][l]` and `m` if `a[k][l]` was zero:

```
if (a[k][l] == 0)
  {
    a[k][l] = 1;
    m--;
  }
```

Point 3 can be most easily fixed by creating a separate function that does resetting of single array elements with bounds checking. Since I assume this is homework, I am not going to write this for you, unless you have made an honest try yourself first. The function signature could look like this:

```
/*
   Set value of `a[line][column]` to zero and increment `*m` if value
   was changed.
   Nothing is done if `line` or `column` are out of bounds.
*/
 void matrix_element_reset(int n, a[n][n], int line, int column, int *m);
```

You can then easily reset array elements around `a[k][l]` like this:

```
/* This can be simplified with loops */
matrix_element_reset(n, a, k-1, l, &m);
matrix_element_reset(n, a, k, l, &m);
matrix_element_reset(n, a, k+1, l, &m);
.....
```

Point 4: Your variable `n` stores the dimension of your matrix. Use it.

Comment: My purpose is not to "let you do my homework", but to understand what I am doing wrong. This would be a small part of a project (where I certainly don't have to fill the matrix with 0s and 1s). It is an exercise that I am doing for myself to be able to understand how this thing works, so that I can do my project with more awareness. Anyway, I found your advice very precious.

Comment: My code still has some problems, but it is now much more readable and I am sure that soon I will be able to find the solution. If you want to take a look, the code is in the edited post. In any case, thank you very much for your precious help.